# A movie about two children growing up together on an island

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this English movie about in 2000 on TV. At that time, TV channels did not show the title of the movie. I only came to know about the movie title via advertisements. However, I couldn't find the title for this one. Here is the details I remember.

There are two children, a boy and a girl, growing up together at remote island. On this island, there are some tribesman who come to worship at certains days. In start, there was an old man along with these children, but he dies soon. Later, they had a child. I also remember the ending very well. In the end, their child accidentally eats some kind of seed or plant food which they assumed is poisonous. Since they could not bear death of their child, they also eat it.

Since I watched it on TV, I do not know in which year it was released.

I googled, but could not find and did not know exactly how to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: It is interesting as entering "two children lost in an island" on Google returns "The Blue Lagoon" on the first page, first position ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [The Blue Lagoon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080453/combined) from 1980 with Brooke Shields.

> Two young children are the sole survivors of a shipwreck in a time when sailing was the only way of travel. They are stranded on a tropical island, a real paradise. Together, Richard and Emmeline have to survive, which is quite easy as there are no dangerous animals on the island. Years later, the two teenagers are living in a self-constructed hut, strange emotions start influencing their relationship. Although they had no grown-ups to educate them for all that time, the behaviour of the two always stayed in a very civilized way. Nature takes its course, and Emmeline gets pregnant, totally unaware of the fact that a child is growing inside her. On the night their boy is born, Richard finds out about the origins of the drums they hear from time to time from the forbidden side of the island.

All the plot points you mentioned are there, including the end (their child eats poison berries, and they do the same). Here's the trailer:

Comment: by looking at the trailer, it seems the one. Thnkx

Comment: @AJ No problem. Followed by a [1991 sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_the_Blue_Lagoon) with Milla Jovovich.

Comment: There was a movie named Blue Lagoon The Awakening. I did not watch it though. But is it also a sequel of that movie?

Comment: It's a sort of remake. They're all based on a [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Lagoon_%28novel%29), anyway.